# Added Unity DI framwork, and now get error "The type UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate."

Tags: c#, umbraco, unity-container

I added the Unity DI framework as a nuget package to my Umbraco solution. My unity configuration file looks like this:

```
public static class UnityConfig
{
    #region Unity Container
    private static Lazy<IUnityContainer> container =
      new Lazy<IUnityContainer>(() =>
      {
          var container = new UnityContainer();
          RegisterTypes(container);
          return container;
      });

    public static IUnityContainer Container => container.Value;
    #endregion

    public static void RegisterTypes(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        container.RegisterType<IHomeViewModelFactory, HomeViewModelFactory>(new PerResolveLifetimeManager());
    }
}
```

I can launch the website, but once I try to access the Umbraco backoffice I get:

**The type UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.**

More specifically the log file says:

```
ERROR Umbraco.Core.UmbracoApplicationBase - An unhandled exception occurred
Unity.Exceptions.ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = 'Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute', name = '(none)'.
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was: 
  Resolving Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute,(none)
 ---> System.InvalidOperationException: The type UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute has multiple constructors of length 1. Unable to disambiguate.
   at Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.Selection.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`1.FindLongestConstructor(Type typeToConstruct)
   at Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.Selection.ConstructorSelectorPolicyBase`1.SelectConstructor(IBuilderContext context, IPolicyList resolverPolicyDestination)
   at Unity.ObjectBuilder.BuildPlan.DynamicMethod.Creation.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.CreateInstanceBuildupExpression(DynamicBuildPlanGenerationContext buildContext, IBuilderContext context)
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: For Umbraco, you may want to [follow their Unity example](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/reference/using-ioc#unity-example) as a guideline of what's needed to work properly.

Comment: Looks like the Unity example in the link you refer to is outdated (f.ex. types that cannot be resolved).

Answer (score 4):

Try adding this to unity config

```
container.RegisterType<Name of Controller>(new InjectionConstructor());
```

Answer (score 2):

In `UnityConfig.cs`, addind the following statement will resolve the issue:

```
container.RegisterType<UmbracoAuthorizeAttribute>(new InjectionConstructor());
```